# Web page looks different in UIWebView and mobile safari

Tags: css, uiwebview, responsive-design

Strange issue found I have.
UIWebView renders the same page different way.
[image]
I've learned a couple of similar questions on SO and tried their solutions (they were about User-Agent header and 'viewport' meta tag) but nothing helped.
Does some one have any ideas? On a picture first screenshot is UIWebView (green and red borders are added to visialize the borders of UIWebView and its nested UIScrollView elements) and the second one is mombile Safari.
Also I analyzed the structure in both cases under web inspector and they look absolutely identical

Comment: why not setting the container to 100% width?

Comment: you're partially right. width:100% fixes the problem. the problem is that the web site doesn't belong to me, I can not force its owners to change css

Comment: It must be a bug- you should/might want to report it to them. But it looks like the first screen shot it landscape?

Comment: yeah, they're both in landscape